# Need help with delete record in asp.net using Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I have this code to delete contact from my database and I have got this error:`No persister for: System.Int32`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

  config.AddAssembly("ContactDomain");

  NHibernate.ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
  NHibernate.ISession session = factory.OpenSession();

  NHibernate.ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

  Contact contact = new Contact();
  int contactid = 1;

  session.Delete(contactid);

  transaction.Commit();
  session.Close();
}
```

I have this code for creating new contact and it's working:

```
protected void btnSaveContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

   config.AddAssembly("ContactDomain");

   NHibernate.ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
   NHibernate.ISession session = factory.OpenSession();

   NHibernate.ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

   Contact contact = new Contact();

   contact.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
   contact.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
   contact.Email = txtEmail.Text;
   contact.Telephone = txtTelephone.Text;

   session.Save(contact);
   transaction.Commit();
   session.Close();
}
```

Comment: One quick comment, you really should be building the session factory `BuildSessionFactory` once on application startup... I assume this is just test code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete an entity that is not saved! try:

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
int contactid = 1; //are you managing manually entity id?


session.SaveOrUpdate(contact);

session.Delete(contact);
```

**update**

```
Contact contact=session.Get<Contact>(1);

session.Delete(contact);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because you're not assigning the Id to the entity.

Comment: also how to make the code to delete the record entered in the text box?

Comment: NHibernate assign automatically the ID. To delete the entity you have to load the entity and then call session.Delete(yourEntity);

Answer (score 2):

If you want only delete entity class then use Load method  instead of Get method. Get method make call to database if the entity does not exist in first level cache. Load method create uninitialized proxy object that does not actually hit the database until you invoke a property/method of the object.

```
Contact contact=session.Load<Contact>(1);
session.Delete(contact);
```